# Is there a a way to call jquery functions dynamically from a .NET dll or class library?

Tags: jquery, wcf, class

I want to use some of the methods in:  faker.js  https://github.com/Marak/Faker.js

to generate random data for my daily unit tests for our WCF services.

has anyone every done this before ?  normal console apps do not even have a script folder so I would

probably have to register the scripts dynamically to start and invoke them via code behind.

thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried registering the function you want in scriptmanager? Also, are you using the .Net ajax framework?

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0 , I am not using the .NET ajax framework though , how do you use the scriptmanager in a console applcation ?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (i.e. jQuery) runs in a browser, and is interpreted by the browser. I don't know of any JavaScript engines you can reference from a console application. If you want to use a JavaScript library, you would need to do this in a web application and running in a browser, not from a console app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) platform for executing JavaScript on the server.

If you take a closer look in the header of [Faker.js](https://github.com/Marak/Faker.js) file you linked to you will see node.js usage sample:

```
        ### node.js -          
        var Faker = require('./Faker');          
        var randomName = Faker.Name.findName(); // Rowan Nikolaus
```